GET API doesn't work in Postman whereas it's working in the browser
I have an API call where I am using GET function in Postman. I am trying to use the same url in browser with a bearer token, I am able to get the data whereas when I am using the same bearer token, I am not getting a response using Postman. Instead I am getting the output shown below when I am using the same.
Output from postman:
{
    "data": [],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "limit": 99
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://xxxxxx/netbackup/admin/jobs?page%5Blimit%5D=99&sort=-startTime,jobId&filter=clientName%20eq%20'xxxx'"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "https://xxxxx/netbackup/admin/jobs?page%5Blimit%5D=99&sort=-startTime,jobId&filter=clientName%20eq%20'xxxx'"
        }
    }
}

Content-Type: Application/json
How to obtain the data using GET API call? Data is not being populated and returned in Postman.
API call doesn't work on the GET function. Using Python language.

May I suggest you to examine all the Request Headers in the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools? Once you have them, please compare these headers with those you're using in Postman. Also if not already done try disabling SSL certificate verification in Postman( Settings > General and turning off SSL certificate verification)
